# How do you re-order stories in a backlog

Tags: azure-devops

How do you re-order priorities of stories within a feature in a backlog within an Azure DevOps board?  I thought all I needed to do was drag and drop the story (see screenshot).  So basically I want to use the order of the stories showing up under the Feature as a way to indicate priority/order of implementation of the story.  However, I seem to be unable to move/re-order the stories.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to drag and drop them?

Comment: Yes, I did.  I guess that's the question.  Why isn't it allowing me to drag and drop them?  Is there some special permission you have to have to do that.  It would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop on the backlog requires an [access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops) of Basic. Stakeholders are allowed to edit existing work items but not reorder them on the backlog.

The [user hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) is where you can assign licenses and check which license you have.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the last 3 stories have a different area path that is not "owned" by the "Humana Enterprise Platform" team. See the (i) to the left of the Work Item Type field. You can reorder work items that are "owned" by the team.